# Why is it whenever i render my object the shadows disappear?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, lighting, shadows

Whenever I render my donut the shadows disapear, even when im in camera mode (ctrl+alt+0), but the shadows are casted just fine when I use viewport shading. (I'm completely new to blender)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe you've disabled a light for render, check the Outliner settings

Comment: Nope, but found the problem, i had selected my light as local camera...

Comment: But appreciate the quick answer, it led me to the solution:-)

Comment: @daskbosse If you want to switch to camera view, the shortcut is Numpad 0 (Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0 is to align the camera to the viewport view, which means you will always change your camera's location and rotation if you use this shortcut). I guess what you have done is, you forgot the Alt key and just clicked Ctrl + Numpad 0 while you had the light selected. This shortcut is "Set Active Object As Camera". You can see in your screenshots that the shadow is there, but behind the donut in view direction (because you're viewing from the location of the light as you already found out).